# Import file mismatch

Tags: python, docker-compose, pytest, fastapi

I'got this error when i'm trying to run `docker-compose exec api pytest`, i think that it can be my dockerfiles.:

```
import file mismatch:
imported module 'test.test_api' has this __file__ attribute:
  /code/api/test/test_api.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
  /code/test/test_api.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules
```

My structure:

[image]

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /code

# TODO: Multstage build, so the container does not runs with a compiler
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl build-essential unixodbc-dev wait-for-it -y

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get remove build-essential -y

COPY ./api /code/

EXPOSE 8000
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    command: ["uvicorn", "api.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]
    volumes:
      - ./api:/code/api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude the `__pycache__` directories from being included when copying your content into the Docker container (in particular because they've only relevant for your current interpreter, which may not be the same as the interpreter inside your container).

Add `__pycache__` to `.dockerignore`. Google Cloud Platform [maintains a sensible default exclusion file for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/blob/main/optional-kubernetes-engine/.dockerignore):

```
__pycache__
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.pyd
.Python
env
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt
.tox
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
*.log
.git
.mypy_cache
.pytest_cache
.hypothesis
```